# Pygtk Liststore most recent call last after Liststore update

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, gtk, pygtk

I created simple code in PyGtk that displays a list of names. After clicking the Update button, the list of names will be updated. Unfortunately, I can't get rid of the "most recent call last" error that appears after clicking the Update button. Can anyone advise me on the problem? This is probably a problem with a line of code under "# select and row".

***EDIT:***
Script returns error message:

> ```
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/radek/Desktop/stackowr1.py", line 18, in choiceRow
>     line = model[treeiter][0]
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 849, in __getitem__
>     aiter = self._getiter(key)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 837, in _getiter
>     aiter = self.get_iter(key)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 871, in get_iter
>     path = self._coerce_path(path)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 846, in _coerce_path
>     return TreePath(path)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 1210, in __new__
>     path = ":".join(str(val) for val in path)
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
> ```

My code:

````
```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.set_border_width(3)
        self.set_default_size(800, 600)

        self.name1 = "John"
        self.name2 = "George"

        def choiceRow(selection):
            model, treeiter = selection.get_selected()
            line = model[treeiter][0]
            print(line)

        def update_name(self):
            self.name1 = "Jeane"
            self.name2 = "Margot"
            print(self.name1, self.name2)
            win.liststore.clear()
            win.liststore.append([self.name1])
            win.liststore.append([self.name2])

        button = Gtk.Button(label = "Update")
        button.connect("clicked", update_name)

        self.layout = Gtk.Layout()

        self.tree = Gtk.TreeView()
        self.liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str)
        self.tree.set_model(self.liststore)
        self.liststore.append([self.name1])
        self.liststore.append([self.name2])
        render = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        self.column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("ID", render, text=0)
        self.tree.append_column(self.column)

        # select a row
        selectetRow = self.tree.get_selection()
        selectetRow.connect("changed", choiceRow)

        self.layout.put(self.tree, 0,0)
        self.layout.put(button, 0,100)

        self.add(self.layout)

win = MyWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
````

Comment: The actual error is at the _end_ of the message; "most recent call last" is just the _beginning_. Please [edit] your question to include the full error message, so that we can help. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: I apologize for the lack. I added an error that the script returns.

Comment: `NoneType` isn't a thing in Python. Did you mean `None`?

Comment: I'm sure this is NoneType. Maybe it's a PyGtk thing. The main problem is in the line "model, treeiter = selection.get_selected ()" I can't handle this error.

Comment: I meant that you should replace `NoneType` in your code with `None`, and see how that works. The error message is saying that `NoneType` is not defined.

Comment: I apologize again. Now I have entered the correct error message. Please ask again for a possible correction. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It looks like a bug :-(
https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=10263

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gtk.TreeSelection.get_selected](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeSelection.html#Gtk.TreeSelection.get_selected) returns `None` when nothing is selected, after the update call there's nothing selected so you get `None` for `treeiter` and you try to access `model[None][0]` which obviously must fail. You need to check whether the returned `iter` is valid before trying to use it so just change your `choiceRow` function to

```py
def choiceRow(selection):
     model, treeiter = selection.get_selected()
     if treeiter:
          line = model[treeiter][0]
          print(line)
```

Comment: Vojto, moc díky. Netušil jsem, že to jde takto vyřešit!
Vojta, thanx a lot!